# How go give $value to wp_query

Tags: wp-query

Probly easy question but just cant seem to find whats wrong. I cant build a query based on a search when i use ' ' but not when i use a alrdy declared variable.

This works

```
$query2 = new WP_Query( 's='motorkap met' );
 while( $query2->have_posts() ) {
            $query2->the_post();
echo the_title();?> </br> <?php
}
```

This doesnt for some reason.... I cant seem to find how to pass the already declared variable

```
$zoekterm = removeCommonWords('motorkap met'); 

$query2 = new WP_Query( 's=$zoekterm' );
 while( $query2->have_posts() ) {
            $query2->the_post();
echo the_title();?> </br> 
}
```

Very stupid I know but been searching for over 2 hours alrdy :( must be passing it wrong somehow tried everything from echo, to just $zoekterm to 's='$zoekterm' ' etc...

Comment: Did you try `"s=$zoekterm"` too? Note the double quotes.

Comment: just tried didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `removeCommonWords()` returns a string, you can do the following:

```
$zoekterm = removeCommonWords('motorkap met'); 

$query2 = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        's' => $zoekterm
    ) 
);

while( $query2->have_posts() ) {
    $query2->the_post();
    echo the_title() . '</br> ';
}
```

Sometimes the array notating is more useful than the string notation ...

Comment: thanks a lot, this works could have taken me ages to find...

Fast question now that I got your attention how do I set it that it only searches the title and not content. If thats alright to ask, don't want to be a gimme the code guy. Ill go on google search hunt if needed. Very happy that this works alrdy.